# Why on set state in react throws Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps-api

I'm using React Google Maps API, and every time that I run this function, when drag end a marker it throws the exception `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')` if I try to run the `setSelectedBusPoint()` and `setAdjacenteBusPoint()` hook.

Here is the code:

```js
function onDragEnd(e) {
        const lat = e.latLng.lat();
        const lng = e.latLng.lng();

        const tempBusPoints = route.direction !== "IDA E VOLTA" ? { ...busPoints } : [...busPoints];
        const tempAdjacenteBusPoints = [...adjacenteBusPoints];

        const index = tempAdjacenteBusPoints.indexOf(tempAdjacenteBusPoints.find(bp => bp.id === id));

        const draggedBusPoint = tempAdjacenteBusPoints[index];

        draggedBusPoint.state = currentDirection === "go" ? "added-go" : "added-return";
        draggedBusPoint.color = "green";
        draggedBusPoint.lat = lat;
        draggedBusPoint.lng = lng;

        if (draggedBusPoint.order === null) {
            if (orderType === "manually") {
                setSelectedBusPoint(draggedBusPoint);
            } else if (orderType === "sequencially") {
                if (currentDirection === "go") {
                    const goMaxOrder = Math.max(...tempBusPoints.goBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order).concat(tempAdjacenteBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.state === "added-go" && bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order))) + 1;

                    tempBusPoints.returnBusPoints.forEach(bp => {
                        if (bp.order !== null) {
                            bp.order += 1;
                            bp.state = bp.state === "updated" || bp.state === "normal" ? "updated" : bp.state;
                            bp.color = "green";
                        }
                    });

                    tempAdjacenteBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null && bp.state === "added-return").forEach(bp => {
                        bp.order += 1;
                    });

                    draggedBusPoint.order = goMaxOrder;

                    setOrder(Math.max(...tempBusPoints.goBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order).concat(tempBusPoints.returnBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order)).concat(tempAdjacenteBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.state === "added-go" || bp.state === "added-return" && bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order))) + 1);

                    setBusPoints(tempBusPoints);
                } else if (currentDirection === "return") {
                    const returnMaxOrder = Math.max(...tempBusPoints.returnBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order).concat(tempAdjacenteBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.state === "added-return" && bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order))) + 1;

                    draggedBusPoint.order = returnMaxOrder;

                    setOrder(Math.max(...tempBusPoints.goBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order).concat(tempBusPoints.returnBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order)).concat(tempAdjacenteBusPoints.filter(bp => bp.state === "added-go" || bp.state === "added-return" && bp.order !== null).map(bp => bp.order))) + 1);

                    setBusPoints(tempBusPoints);
                }
            }
            
            setAdjacenteBusPoints(tempAdjacenteBusPoints);
        } else {
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Show the code that throws the error

Comment: @GuyIncognito it is exactly this code, if you are refering to the full code is a large repository that i can't show here

Comment: It's not possible for this code to throw a "Cannot read properties of null (reading **'toString'**)" error, there isn't any `toString` here anywhere. If you can't find the code that throws the error, at least show the full error message. The error message shows the file and line number of the error.

Answer (score -1):

check the value of the variable first before adding the `.toString` prototype. or you can search for errors with `try catch` code

```js
let arr = [123,"abc",false,null,undefined,NaN,[],{},,]
for(let i of arr){
  try{
   console.log(i.toString(), 'success')
   // solution `i?.toString()`
   }catch(e){
     console.log('err',i,e.message)
   }
}
```